# R error (fisher test): all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite

Tags: r, statistics

I have to test if bees of 2 different treatment groups (CTRL and DWV) have a preference to collect nectar vs pollen using a Fisher's exact test.

```
data=structure(list(TREATMENT = structure(1:2, .Label = c("CTRL", 
                                                 "DWV"), class = "factor"), 
POLLEN_BIN.sum = c(35, 27), NECTAR_BIN.sum = c(48, 

9)), .Names = c("TREATMENT", "POLLEN_BIN.sum", "NECTAR_BIN.sum"

), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
fisher.test(data)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in fisher.test(data) : 
  all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite
```

I do not see what is wrong about my 2x2 matrix though

Additional info:

```
R version: 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle"
OS: Windows 10 64
```

Thanks in advance for trying to help.

Comment: You should use only columns 2 and 3   `fisher.test(data[,2:3])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time you should make your data like this

```
data <- data.frame(POLLEN_BIN.sum=c(35,27),
                  NECTAR_BIN.sum=c(38,9))
rownames(data) <- c("CTRL","DWV")

#      POLLEN_BIN.sum NECTAR_BIN.sum
# CTRL             35             38
# DWV              27              9
```

*This keeps rownames separate from the data*

Then the following works

```
 fisher.test(data)

 # data:  data
 # p-value = 0.008066
```